# F# .fsx script: how to register 'paket' as package manager?

Tags: .net-core, f#

any help appreciated!

## Objective & Problem

- Objective: Use F# as scripting language on Linux, while resolving and installing automatically the package dependencies
- Problem: The `#r` loading of Nuget package assemblies via Paket doesn't work

In that simplified example, I will use `Fake` to run a system command:

```
#r "paket:
nuget Fake.Core"

open Fake.Core

printfn "Test OK"
```

When I run the script, I got the following error:

```sh
$ dotnet fsi test.fsx

/home/mat/fsx-test/test.fsx(1,1): error FS3216: Package manager key 'paket' was not registered in [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.403/FSharp; /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.403/FSharp/], []. Currently registered: nuget

/home/mat/fsx-test/test.fsx(1,1): error FS3217: Processing of a script fragment has stopped because an exception has been raised
```

## System Information

```
$ which paket
/home/mat/.dotnet/tools/paket
```

```
$ dotnet --info
mat0cebcbce666:~/fsx-test# dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.403
 Commit:    9e895200cd

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     debian
 OS Version:  10
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         debian.10-arm
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.403/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.9
  Commit:  774fc3d6a9

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.403 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.9 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.9 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: Did you initialize the directory for paket as described in the getting started? https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/get-started.html

Comment: just skip paket and use nuget directly, paket won't give you that much extra.

Comment: as mentioned in @LuisFX 's link you need either to copy the dll or reference compilertool albeit option two does not work for me atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can only use dotnet 5 to use that feature. Check out this small sample:

https://github.com/nojaf/fsharp5-script-docker-sample